# Reading the first few columns and rows of a dataset instead of the whole dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to read the first few lines of my dataset instead of the whole dataset. Below is the code that I typed and outputted the whole dataset.

`df = pd.read_csv ('C:\\Users\\CMuasya\\downloads\\unresolved_data.csv') print (df)`

what should I add to output the first 10 columns ?

Comment: `df.iloc[:, :10]` would do the work. And read `Dataframe ` documentation and stackoverflow asking question guidelines in order to ask a good question.

Comment: `df.iloc[:, :10]` would do the work. And read `Dataframe ` documentation and stackoverflow asking question guidelines in order to ask a good question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - Read only first few lines of each rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168254/pandas-read-only-first-few-lines-of-each-rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
df[0:10] or df.head(10) # 10 rows.
```

and

```
df[:, 0:10] # 10 columns.
```

You should look at Python slicers.

Comment: appreciate, you are a life saver